Laravel Filamat 3.2 export permission file
Filamat version 3.2. The Excel output I receive has its permission set to root, preventing users from downloading it. We haven't found a solution yet. I've tried commands like chmod 777 and chown www-data, but they didn't work. Do you have any solutions?

Did you mean Laravel Filament?
